# Inverse Superposition

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, function-construction, code-review

There are 4 tables that, I have written them as bellow: (m, n, s, and r are orthogonal basis. r.r=n.n=m.m=s.s=1, and m.n=n.r=...=0). a's, b's, c's and d's are coefficients and are numeric values.

```
1: a1*m+a2*n+a3*s+a4*r
2: b1*m+b2*n+b3*s+b4*r
3: c1*m+c2*n+c3*s+c4*r
4: d1*m+d2*n+d3*s+d4*r
```

(eq.1 is another base for new space and is orthogonal with 3 others). The main purpose is the finding of pi's in such a way that:

```
p1(a1*m+a2*n+a3*s+a4*r)
+p2(b1*m+b2*n+b3*s+b4*r)
+p3( c1*m+c2*n+c3*s+c4*r)
+p4( d1*m+d2*n+d3*s+d4*r)=n
```

In other words, one way is solving these sets of equations with unknown pi's to obtain them.

```
p1a1+p2b1+p3c1+p4d1=0
p1a2+p2b2+p3c2+p4d2=1
p1a3+p2b3+p3c3+p4d3=0
p1a4+p2b4+p3c4+p4d4=0
```

Not only, once the coefficient of `n` in the right side of equations maybe is `1`, but also, (in another case) the coefficient of `m` maybe is `1`.

The solving way for the last sets of equations is straightforward in *Mathematica*, but I am searching a way in which with taking the tables of coefficient for example: {{a1,a2,a3,a4},{b1,b2,b3,b4},...}, the desire situation can obtained. (desire situation is obtaining pi's to get final results of the last equation set.

My solution is in here:

I put all of coefficient in a table:

```
table={{a1,a2,a3,a4},{b1,b2,b3,b4},{c1,c2,c3,c4},{d1,d2,d3,d4}};
```

Then, I defined:

```
equation = eq = ConstantArray[0, {4}];
pi = {p1, p2, p3, p4};
ii = (for example here for n ii=2, for m ii=1, for s ii=3 and so on)



Do[Do[
If[j == ii,
  equation[[ii]] += pi[[i]]*table[[i, ii]], 
  equation[[j]] += pi[[i]]*table[[i, j]]],
  {i, 1, 4}], {j, 1, 4}];

Do[
If[j == ii, eq[[j]] = equation[[j]] == 1, 
eq[[j]] = equation[[j]] == 0], {j, 1, 4}];

Solve[{eq[[1]], eq[[2]], eq[[3]], eq[[4]]},{p1,p2,p3,p4}]
```

But my solution is long, How can I shorten the above process? Also, if the number of equations and unknowns be large, the above process will not be so good!

Comment: You are saying that `a1*m+a2*n+a3*s+a4*r` …  ` d1*m+d2*n+d3*s+d4*r` is another orthogonal basis. To figure components of vector `n` in this new basis you have to project `n` on all basis vectors, i.e. `n.(a1*m+a2*n+a3*s+a4*r)=p1`. This is true for normalized orthogonal basis only (for the general case of basis you will need to replace `Dot` with bi-linear form)

Comment: You are right, Then we do not need to solve anymore! Unfortunately I have late received to this result. (that being base of another set)!!!

Comment: Err.. not sure what's unfortunate.. but I'm if it helped…